# SQL Identity(1,1) as a Default constrain

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to define a new table as follows and I want the `IndexPosition` column to get the `MAX(IndexPosition) + 1` by default.

```
CREATE TABLE SpeechOutputList
(ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
IndexPosition int DEFAULT (???),
SpeechConfigCode nvarchar(36) NOT NULL,
OutputSentence nvarchar(500),
PRIMARY KEY(ID),
FOREIGN KEY(SpeechConfigCode) REFERENCES SpeechConfig ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

I want to allow the user to set it's own custom number, but if he hasn't supplied any such number, the default would be the `MAX(IndexPosition) + 1`.

I thought about `DEFAULT IDENTITY(1,1)` but it's impossible.

I also thought about: `DEFAULT SELECT MAX(IndexPosition) + 1 FROM SpeechOutputList` but it's impossible too (Error: 'Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.').

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Instead of `DEFAULT` identity, you should be able to put a regular identity on there that will be used in the absence of one provided

Comment: @JeffPuckettII - Nope. Only one `IDENTITY` column per table. And identity columns aren't updatable anyway.

Comment: Is there any requirement that IndexPosition will be `<= ID`? Otherwise what happens if someone enters a very large IndexPosition such as max int?

Comment: you need to use insert TRIGGER. and in your trigger set IndexPosition to ID+1 if it is null.

Comment: There is no such requirement. I just tried achieve that by 'IDENTITY(1,1)' but this column can contains max int number and even duplicate numbers. @MartinSmith

Comment: @Jacob - Well if someone ends up inserting max int any attempt to use `MAX(IndexPosition) + 1` is going to be doomed.

Comment: Yes, you right. So it brings me to to some more validations before inserting, thanks for the notice. I'll validate this in my code then. @MartinSmith

Comment: Is there any simply  way to do so? Without triggers, stored procedure, etc... My company try to prevent such external functions since it is, relatively, hard to maintain. Thanks. @FLICKER

Comment: @Jacob, As you may have some validation, in my opinion you have to use some proc or trigger. why using proc or function while trigger is much easier and doesn't need any external coding?

Comment: Do you actually want `MAX(IndexPosition) + 1` or would "use a value that's not currently used" be adequate?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using a SEQUENCE object.

SEQUENCE objects are more flexible than the IDENTITY property. They are not bound to one table and you can use the same SEQUENCE object in multiple places if need be. They also give better performance.

Create a SEQUENCE object, specifying the data type (int), the starting value, and how much to increment by.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.IndexPositionSequence
    AS int
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1;
```

Then create the table, and use the NEXT VALUE FOR function to get a value from the SEQUENCE object.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SpeechOutputList
(
    ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    IndexPosition int DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR IndexPositionSequence),
    SpeechConfigCode nvarchar(36) NOT NULL,
    OutputSentence nvarchar(500),
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
)
```

Then we can insert some values into the table. Some of the values have IndexPosition specified and others not.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.SpeechOutputList (IndexPosition, SpeechConfigCode, OutputSentence)
    VALUES
        (123, N'abcd', N'The quick brown fox'),
        (DEFAULT, N'efgh', N'jumped over the'),
        (124, N'ijkl', N'lazy dog'),
        (DEFAULT, N'mnop', N'and some cats');
```

Then display what's in the table.

```
SELECT *
   FROM dbo.SpeechOutputList;
```

[image]

See MSDN > CREATE SEQUENCE (Transact-SQL): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx

Comment: This will increment in pace with the number of times no explicit value is supplied. Not the `MAX(IndexPosition)` as requested. i.e. If 10 rows are inserted and 2 hit the default and the other 8 supply explicit values the next value generated will be 3 so it likely won't end up positioned at the end as desired.

Comment: @MartinSmith But OP also said tried DEFAULT IDENTITY(1,1)

Comment: Using MAX(IndexPosition) could be problematic. What happens if a user types in 2147483647? Also does the IndexPosition have to be unique?

Answer (score 1):

This is my suggestion

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.DataTable
(
ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
IndexPosition int,
Name varchar(10)
)
go
create trigger dbo.AI_DataTable on dbo.DataTable
after insert
as
begin
  declare @id int = (select ID from inserted)
  declare @ip int = (select IndexPosition from inserted)
  print @id
  print @ip
  if (@ip is null)
  begin
    update dbo.DataTable 
    set IndexPosition = @id + 1
    where ID = @id
  end
end

-- you can implement any logic in trigger
-- Note: support bulk insert in trigger

insert into  dbo.DataTable(Name) values ('First')

insert into dbo.DataTable (Name) values ('Second')

select * from dbo.DataTable
```

Result:

```
+----+---------------+--------+
| ID | IndexPosition |  Name  |
+----+---------------+--------+
|  1 |             2 | First  |
|  2 |             3 | Second |
+----+---------------+--------+
```

Comment: This will fail if multiple rows are inserted in a single statement. `insert into  dbo.DataTable(Name) values ('First'), ('Second')`

Comment: @MartinSmith, I already have mentioned in the comment that bulk insert should be handled.

Answer (score 0):

I am not at the computer I did this on but I think I have it figured out
I tested this
You can have a Function as a default vaulue
Just have a function that returns the value
Make the function the default value

```
select isnull(max(IndexPosition),0) + 1 from table;
```